# Descriptors matching on a cylinder

Tags: opencv, matching, orb

I want to try and match descriptors (such as ORB) from a 2D images with this 2D image mapped on a cylinder.

Example: I want to recognize a sticker on a bottle.

How would you do a robust matching?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show us what you already tried and what is not working.

Comment: So far, for 2 images we used the findHomography from opencv: it tries to find an homography between the matching corners through a Ransac approach. If the number of inlier is high enough we consider there is a match.

Comment: So far, we have a short experience for 2 images: we used the findHomography from opencv. It tries to find an homography between the matching corners through a Ransac approach. If the number of inlier is high enough we consider there is a match. For an image on a cylinder, We were considering using symetry test only but in 2D we already had some false positives. My question comes from: Vuforia works nicely on cylinders (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOe7qly9-7I) so I was thinking maybe there is a "classical" trick for cylinders? We have to implement our own findHomography for cylinders?